# Heroku share database in pipeline with restricted permissions?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-pipelines

I have a production and staging app in my pipeline. I would like to do one of two things.

1. Copy the postgres production database, but with limited data (as the current amount requires that I pay). Really, I want to copy all of the data except from one table. Is it possible to copy it and then just delete a table?
2. If this is not possible, can I share the production database with the staging app but not allow it to add or delete data unless I know it is ready.